# Surface area of a sphere limits

Tags: calculus, geometry, surfaces

If I am finding the surface area of a sphere in spherical coordinates my intergral would be like this:

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 R^2 \sin (\theta) d\phi d\theta =4\pi R^2$$
But if I do the following:

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 R^2 \sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi =0$$

What makes the answers different? In both cases I am integrating over the same total area! What does the last integral represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the confusion is in your integration limits, each integral symbol with its limits corresponds to one and only one variable! Geometrically what you want is:
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0\left( \int^{\pi}_0 R^2 \sin (\theta) d\theta\right) d\phi =2R^2\int^{2\pi}_0d\phi = 4\pi R^2
$$
The problem arises when you integrate $\sin\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, but in spherical coordinates $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 4):

Think about where the $\sin(\theta)$ came from: instead of integrating over the surface area of the sphere, you are integrating over a rectangle in the $\theta-\phi$ plane. The $\sin(\theta)$ term, the determinant of the Jacobian of the map fro the rectangle to the sphere, rescales the infinitesimal area element $d\theta d\phi$ so that you get infinitesimal surface area on the sphere (near the north and south pole, the infinitesimal square $d\theta d\phi$ gets "squished" onto the sphere into a region of much smaller surface area than near the equator.)

When $\theta > \pi$, your second integral asserts that $d\theta d\phi$ gets mapped into a patch on the sphere with negative surface area -- this makes no sense. The correct Jacobian determinant is $|\sin\theta|$ (geometrically, the size of the patch is the same on the front as on the back of the sphere) and you can verify that 
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} R^2 |\sin{\theta}| d\theta d\phi = 4\pi R^2.$$

Comment: Not sure why negative surface area doesn't make sense - the OP has in effect calculated the area of half the sphere minus the area of the other half.  But your point about $|\sin\theta|$ is absolutely (pun intended but regretted) correct.  +1.

Comment: Yes, I guess "doesn't make sense" is too strong. It depends on whether you're treating the area element $dA$ as a measure or as a 2-form; in the former case there is no issue with orientation, the factor you get from change-of-variables is always positive, and intuitively you are evaluating the function 1 on a bunch of tiny parallelograms and measuring how much these get scaled when you map them from the rectangle to the sphere -- and this amount of scaling is always positive.

Comment: If you're treating $dA$ as a form, you must notice that it doesn't pull back to an area form on the rectangle, due to the singularity at $\theta = \pi$ where it vanishes. To fix this you must reverse the orientation of the "back" before integrating, i.e. multiply by -1.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int^{\pi}_0 \int^{2\pi}_0 R^2 \sin (\theta) d\phi d\theta =4\pi R^2$$ is meaningless if you don't specify on which variable you integrate.

I would write : $$\int^{\pi}_{\theta = 0} \int^{2\pi}_{\phi=0} R^2 \sin (\theta) d\phi d\theta =4\pi R^2$$

If you switch the order of $d\theta$ and $d\phi$, it doesn't change the fact that it is $\theta$ which is integrated from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why you can't integrate using the parameterization where $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, instead of the other way around, which does indeed still cover the sphere.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but with your answer (that I have upvoted), there is no point for me to rewrite mine since you answered that perfectly, so I'll let mine as is.